# Postgres recursive traversal of a table

Tags: sql, postgresql, recursive-query

I have a table with columns:
source_table_name,
source_table_full_name,

This table contains lineage information of BigQuery tables and views.
Sample data:

[image]
[image]

Required output:

[image]

The output should bypass the temporary tables and capture the lineage of original source table to the final target table / view.

t_sales_sft_crmy_che_de_4236 is the source table which creates multiple temp tables as well as one view v_sales_sft_crmy_che_de.
one of the temp tables t_sales_sft_crmy_che_de_temp creates t_sales_sft_crmy_che_de. This table should be treated as one of the target tables for t_sales_sft_crmy_che_de_4236 and should be shown in the output.
Other temp table t_p_calendar_national_temp might also have created few temp tables and so on.

I only want source to all the targets created in the output.

I tried multiple drafts of my query but could not figure out.

Comment: Please share your simple data as text so it can be easy for us to help you https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors#:~:text=You%20should%20not%20post%20code,for%20users%20with%20visual%20impairments.

Comment: Here you go:
source_table_name varchar(100),
  target_table_name varchar(100));
t_sales_sft_crmy_che_de_4236', 't_p_calendar_national_temp'),
  ('t_sales_sft_crmy_che_de_4236', 't_p_calendar_national_temp'),
  ('t_sales_sft_crmy_che_de_4236', 't_sales_sft_crmy_che_de_temp'),
  ('t_sales_sft_crmy_che_de_4236', 'v_sales_sft_crmy_che_de');
't_sales_sft_crmy_che_de_temp', 't_sales_sft_crmy_che_de'),
  ('t_sales_sft_crmy_che_de_temp', 't_sales_sft_crmy_che_period_de_temp')

Answer (score 1):

Creating the test data:

```
create table lineage (
  source_table_name varchar(100),
  target_table_name varchar(100));

insert into lineage values
  ('t_sales_sft_crmy_che_de_4236', 't_p_calendar_national_temp'),
  ('t_sales_sft_crmy_che_de_4236', 't_p_calendar_national_temp'),
  ('t_sales_sft_crmy_che_de_4236', 't_sales_sft_crmy_che_de_temp'),
  ('t_sales_sft_crmy_che_de_4236', 'v_sales_sft_crmy_che_de');

insert into lineage values
  ('t_sales_sft_crmy_che_de_temp', 't_sales_sft_crmy_che_de'),
  ('t_sales_sft_crmy_che_de_temp', 't_sales_sft_crmy_che_period_de_temp');

select * from lineage;

      source_table_name       |          target_table_name
------------------------------+-------------------------------------
 t_sales_sft_crmy_che_de_4236 | t_p_calendar_national_temp
 t_sales_sft_crmy_che_de_4236 | t_p_calendar_national_temp
 t_sales_sft_crmy_che_de_4236 | t_sales_sft_crmy_che_de_temp
 t_sales_sft_crmy_che_de_4236 | v_sales_sft_crmy_che_de
 t_sales_sft_crmy_che_de_temp | t_sales_sft_crmy_che_de
 t_sales_sft_crmy_che_de_temp | t_sales_sft_crmy_che_period_de_temp
```

And the solution is :

```
with recursive x (source_table_name, target_table_name) as (
    select source_table_name, target_table_name
      from lineage
     where source_table_name = 't_sales_sft_crmy_che_de_4236'
    union all
    select l.source_table_name, l.target_table_name
      from lineage l, x
     where l.source_table_name = x.target_table_name)
 select 't_sales_sft_crmy_che_de_4236' as source_table_name, target_table_name
   from x
  where target_table_name not like '%_temp';

     source_table_name       |    target_table_name
------------------------------+-------------------------
 t_sales_sft_crmy_che_de_4236 | v_sales_sft_crmy_che_de
 t_sales_sft_crmy_che_de_4236 | t_sales_sft_crmy_che_de
```

Comment: Thanks @jerome for the solution. One follow up question though. In your output I see t_sales_sft_crmy_che_de_temp as the source_table_name while it should be t_sales_sft_crmy_che_de_4236 since this is the originating table which created multiple temporary tables to reach to the target table t_sales_sft_crmy_che_de. I do not want temp tables in the output.
First output row is fine as that is a straight forward lineage in the lineage table but the next row is where i want original source table to final target table and no intermediate temporary table

Comment: You're right, I didn't see that... let me check it....

Comment: This is simply hardcoding, isnt it ?
What if i want a generic solution for thousands of such source tables in my lineage table ?

Comment: This is not hardcoding as your root 'source_table_name' is always the input you use to build the query ('t_sales_sft_crmy_che_de_4236'). So if you want to use this query with parameter, replace 't_sales_sft_crmy_che_de_4236' by your input parameter. The query presented here is only because you asked for a specific source table 't_sales_sft_crmy_che_de_4236'.

Comment: Thanks. But I dont want it to be parameterized as well. I am trying to create a view out of this table which capture such lineage of all the tables present in this table.